# What are some use cases of few-shot learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, applications, few-shot-learning

Besides computer vision and image classification, what other use cases/applications are for few-shot learning?

Comment: Anything? A system which can learn from a single example is the holy grail.

Answer (score 3):

Few-short learning (FSL) can be useful for many (if not all) machine learning problems, including supervised learning (regression and classification) and reinforcement learning.

The paper [Generalizing from a Few Examples: A Survey on Few-Shot Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05046.pdf) (2020) provides an overview (including examples of applications and use cases) of FSL. Their definition of FSL provided is based on Tom Mitchell's famous definition of machine learning.

> Definition 2.1 (**Machine Learning** [92, 94]). A computer program is said to learn from experience $E$ with respect to some classes of task $T$ and performance measure $P$ if its performance can improve with $E$ on $T$ measured by $P$.

Here's the definition of FSL.

> Definition 2.2. **Few-Shot Learning** (FSL) is a type of machine learning problems, specified by $E$, $T$ and $P$, where $E$ contains only a limited number of examples with supervised information for the task $T$.

Specific examples of applications of FSL are

- character generation
- drug toxicity discovery
- sentiment classification from short text
- object recognition

Answer (score 0):

An interesting use case is IQ tests, or program synthesis from examples in general.

IQ tests often require you to derive a program from a few examples that can produce a certain output. See for instance https://github.com/fchollet/ARC